# Fun Inference with Low Number of Data Points.

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Apples on my large orchard can either be red or green, I have observed that two apples are red and seen no other apples, what does this tell me about that ratio of red to green apples?

Thanks

Comment: This is a simple Bayesian question. Suppose we know that the prob an apple is red is r. Then the chance that two (presumably randomly and independently chosen) apples are both red is r^2. The question is what prior distribution you take for r. The question is rather silly because it being your orchard, you would have some idea based on past years. Absent any data, there are various possibilities. You can easily calculate the answer for various priors and compare them - eg r=0.5, r is uniformly distributed on the interval (0,1).

Answer (score 2):

The beta family of distributions is commonly used for prior
distribution of the binomial success probability $\theta$.
The first reason is that $(0,1)$ is the support for beta
distributions. The second is that the beta family has many
different shapes. The third is that beta priors are 'conjugate'
to (mathematically compatible with) binomial likelihoods, thus
making distributional computations easy.

Let Success be getting a red apple on a random draw from
your orchard and suppose your prior density is $p(\theta)$ is $Beta(3,3),$ which
means you believe the ratio may be 'somewhere near' 50:50, but
not necessarily 'very close'. In particular $P(.2 < \theta <.8) \approx 0.88.$  Also, as we begin a 90% Bayesian probability
interval for $\theta$ is $(.189, .811).$ In R:

```
 diff(pbeta(c(.2,.8), 3, 3))
 ## 0.88416
 qbeta(c(.05,.95), 3, 3)
 ## 0.1892554 0.8107446
```

Then your binomial likelihood function based on 2 successes out of 2
is $$p(x|\theta) \propto \theta^2 (1 - \theta)^{2-2} = \theta^2,$$
where the symbol $\propto$ indicates that we have omitted
the unnecessary binomial coefficient.

Then Bayes' Theorem says
$$\text{POSTERIOR}  \propto \text{PRIOR} \times \text{LIKELIHOOD}$$
or 
$$p(\theta|x) \propto p(\theta)p(x|\theta) 
\propto \theta^{3-1}(1 - \theta)^{3-1} \times \theta^2 
= \theta^{5-1}(1-\theta)^{3-1},$$
where we recognize at the right, the kernel of $Beta(5,3).$

Thus, our posterior 90% probability interval for $\theta$ is
$(.341, .871)$---slightly more optimistic about
getting red apples from your orchard than before, but then
two observed red apples don't count for a lot if your prior
is even mildly concentrated at '50:50-ish',

```
 qbeta(c(.05,.95), 5, 3)
 ## 0.3412614 0.8712436
```

Note: If we had begun with a noninformative prior $Beta(.5, .5)$
our 90% interval would have gone from prior $(.006, .994)$ to posterior$(.431, .999)$.

```
 qbeta(c(.05,.95), .5, .5)
 ## 0.00615583 0.99384417
 qbeta(c(.05,.95), 2.5, .5)
 ## 0.4307415 0.9991318
```

When we have very little data, the prior distribution makes
a big difference in the posterior. So, indeed as suggested
by @algamest, it really does depend on your prior distribution.
However, an advantage of applied
Bayesian statistics is that yesterday's posterior can be today's
prior. So you can refine your opinion about the proportion of red apples in your
orchard as you continue to (randomly) collect and munch apples over time.

Comment: There is legitimate debate about what constitutes a "noninformative" prior in this case. Your choice $\text{Beta}(.5,.5)$ is one possibility, others being $\text{Beta}(1,1)=U(0,1)$ and the improper prior $\text{Beta}(0,0)$. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_succession#Mathematical_details) and e.g. [this article](http://www.stats.org.uk/priors/noninformative/Smith.pdf) that argues for the latter choice and against the others.

Comment: @joriki: Yes, indeed. Jeffreys prior Beta(.5, .5) has solid theoretical justification, but I judged the rationale for it to be too obscure to discuss at this level. Uniform might have been a better choice at this level, but there are good arguments against it. Improper prior requires add'l tech discussion to use/compute here. Notice I said "a", not "the" noninformative prior. Chose Jeffreys for my end note because it's "half-way" between. With little data, as here, the choice among these three priors does make a real difference. With substantial amounts of data, not so much.